# Need help adding business facebook feed to website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to add our company's facebook feed to our company website. I've looked at facebook's Graph API, but it seems limited to my personal account. I'm an admin for our company's business page, but I can't figure out how to get that accounts feed info, and I don't understand facebook's documentation. Anyone know of a simple, current, step-by-step tutorial?

Comment: You should be able to do this using a page access token and calling the /page/feed endpoint (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed). You can also use the Page Plugin or the Embed Posts plugin.

Comment: Thanks Neil. Here's what that page says: "An access token is required to view publicly shared posts. A user access token is required to retrieve posts visible to that person. A page access token is required to retrieve any other posts." How do you generate an access token for a business page?

Comment: You can do this by hitting the end point "me/accounts". You will need to grant the permission manage_pages to your app in order to do this. it is explained in more detail at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using a page access token and calling the /page/feed endpoint 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed.

You can also use the Page Plugin or the Embed Posts plugin